# Why am I not able to insert a NULL into a nullable DATE column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008r2.

I have a table with a column defined as:

```
TheDate date null
```

When I try to insert a NULL value into this column, I get the error message: "**Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date**".

If I change the data type to datetime, it works fine.

Why does this not work with the date data type?

Thanks.

EDIT:  Lamak is right:

My insert statement was using a select statement as the source, and the source table was created using a "select into" a temp table statement, and apparently, since the table was dynamically defined, the column was assigned the "int" data type when the null was inserted.

Comment: Please show us your insert statement.

Comment: I get the feeling there's quite a lot not being said here.

Comment: I'm trying not to stick five pages of code into one question.

Comment: "If I change it to datetime it works fine, Why doesn't it work with date type". Huh?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not just inserting a `NULL`, you are inserting a `NULL` of datatype `INT`. Insert  this instead: `CAST(NULL AS DATE)`